# where is my mistake in while() loop?

Tags: php

Here is my coding for while() loop i want to know that where i have mistake.

```
<?php
$asb = 'http://themonitors.net/sitelist.php';
// Example of my data =  meetfreeman.com|back-capital.com|bitomine.com|thebillioncoins.com|

 $myfile = fopen($asb, 'r') or die("Unable to open file!");
// Output one line until end-of-file
if ($myfile != '') {
while(!feof($myfile)) {
 $string = fgets($myfile) ."<br><br>";

$matches = split('\|', $string );

    $url  = $matches[0];

     echo $url;
}
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

My while() loop showing just 1st one data ( meetfreeman.com )

Comment: How many do you expect?

Comment: i want all data which is showing in example ( meetfreeman.com|back-capital.com|bitomine.com|thebillioncoins.com|   ) without  |

Comment: Just my two cents. Split is already DEPRECATED from php 5.3 and REMOVED in php 7.0, use explode or str_split().

Comment: Radoslaw can you type the code here using explode or str_split(). i am using php 5.3 hosting

Comment: Code posted below.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look - split() takes more resources than explode().  Use it like this:

**UPDATE**

```
$asb = 'http://themonitors.net/sitelist.php';

$myfile = file_get_contents($asb);
if ($myfile != '') {
  $urls = explode('|', $myfile);
  foreach ($urls as &$url) {
    echo $url;
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: its showing same just one data please check this http://themonitors.net/sitelist.php or Example of my data ( meetfreeman.com|back-capital.com|bitomine.com|thebillioncoins.com|  )

Comment: ah, it's cause there is no line break at http://themonitors.net/sitelist.php - so there is only one line to parse.

Comment: i see what you need.  try that.  you were over thinking it, hahaha.

Answer (score 0):

After `split` function you get an array with all yours values, but in `$url` you take only the first item from it. So `echo $url` outputs only the first item. And you would like to print all `$matches` array wouldn't you?

Your code will be:

```
$asb = 'http://themonitors.net/sitelist.php';
// Example of my data =  meetfreeman.com|back-    capital.com|bitomine.com|thebillioncoins.com|

$myfile = fopen($asb, 'r') or die("Unable to open file!");
// Output one line until end-of-file
if ($myfile != '') {
    while(!feof($myfile)) {
        $string = fgets($myfile) ."<br><br>";
        $matches = split('\|', $string );
        foreach($matches as $matche) {
            echo $matche . "\n";
        }
    }
    } else {
    echo "0 results";
}
fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: am using echo $url because i will insert data into my database one by one

Answer (score 0):

If all of your data is in one line try to use another approach.

```
$data = file_get_contents($file)
$data = explode('|',$data);

if(!empty($data)){
   (...)
}else{
   echo '0 results';
}
```